# Overwrite resource files after installation

Tags: android

I developed an application and I want to create an update package which contains string.xml and styles.xml but no activity (just updated files, not the whole app package), Actually I tried this with same package name but it didn't work, Does android allow me to overwrite these files after installation? How can I do this?
Thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can do that is by updating the existing code with the new styles and strings and updating the application from the distribution means that you have chosen.

Just food for thought :

If you have an application which have a constant change in the strings and styles, then perhaps you can create a dynamic application which fetches these settings from some server and applies these changes on runtime. It entirely depends what is the nature of your application.